# premailer rails not generating text part automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to use premailer-rails to generate text part of email automatically.

```
gem 'hpricot'
gem "premailer-rails"
```

I'm not getting the text part when I look at the actual email.

It seems as if the gem is not enabled. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

If the gem is not working, it may be because you are missing an initializer
Add this code in config/initializers/premailer_rails.rb

```
Premailer::Rails.config.merge!(preserve_styles: true, remove_ids: true)
```

Also

> If you're using this gem outside of Rails, you'll need to call Premailer::Rails.register_interceptors manually in order for it to work. This is done ideally in some kind of initializer, depending on the framework you're using.

You can find this information on the gem's Github page https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails. 
On another note, they also recomend to use nokogiri instead of hpricot, seeing as the latter is no longer mantained.